# What was not allowing Egwene and co. to leave Tel'aran'rhiod in Towers of Midnight?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In Towers of Midnight, Chapter 37: Darkness of Midnight, when fighting Mesaana, Egwene and co are unable to leave the dream. At this time Perrin has already taking the Travelling inhibitor ter'angreal (the dreamspike) to Tar Valon, but in the next Chapter it turns out that although the ter'angreal is still there, they leave the dream. At the beginning I thought it might be the ter'angreal preventing them but here it seems obvious that it was not the case. So what WAS inhibiting them from exiting the dream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was the dreamspike keeping them from shifting away. They couldn't shift to a different place outside of the dreamspike's reach, though they could shift location inside of it.

It doesn't, however, prevent dreamwalkers from waking up, which is what they eventually did.

Comment: Wow, I completely misunderstood what happened here. There was the "Send Brendas out" part and I totally thought that they are speaking of waking later on as well.

Comment: @fbence just to add a point; it's not easy to leave Tel'aran'rhiod willingly for those who are not educated well.